# "А может и" — где ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как верно расставить знаки препинания?

Учебник поможет детям, а может(,) и взрослым(,) расширить словарный запас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ:

**Учебник поможет детям, а может и взрослым,  расширить словарный запас.**

Союзное соединение  ***а может*** относится к обособленному члену предложения и не отделяется от него.

Комментарий ко второму ответу:

***Учебник поможет детям, а может и взрослым расширить словарный запас**.*

Такой вариант теоретически возможен, но **вряд ли он имелся в виду**.

Выглядит он **неестественно**  и по содержанию, и с точки зрения порядка слов.

К примеру,  непонятно, чем именно он поможет детям, договаривать надо.

Более приемлемо он выглядел бы так: *Учебник поможет детям (в чем-то), а взрослым может  расширить словарный запас.*

Comment: Интересный момент: вводное слово/сочетание в начале обособленного оборота не отделяется, но оно же не в начале, а после союза А.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ставится только перед союзом а. После **может** запятая не нужна, так оно выступает здесь не в роли вводного слова, а в роли сказуемого.

**Учебник поможет детям, а может и взрослым расширить словарный запас**.

Пример **может** в качестве вводного слова:

**Учебник поможет детям, а может, и взрослым расширит словарный запас.**

Answer (score 0):

Самый удачный вариант пунктуации по смыслу и для прочтения:
*Учебник поможет детям, а может, и взрослым расширить словарный запас.* || Простое предложение.

Вариант Sharon равносилен следующему (и его лучше оформить так, потому что запятые для вставки явление редкое, как авторская пунктуация):
*Учебник поможет детям — а может, и взрослым — расширить словарный запас.*
Вставка здесь не очень удачна для текстового описания учебника: там как бы дети и взрослые идут наравне, не стоит одно обособлять, лучше, чтобы и структурно они шли наравне. А ещё это не та информация, которую можно изъять без ущерба, она как бы основная по важности, не дополнительная. Да и такого типа вставки в описаниях не используются, оно не уместно. Но с другой стороны, "а может" способствует обособленной конструкции. Так что противоречие. Удачнее сделать так:
*Учебник поможет детям расширить словарный запас. А может, и взрослым.* || "И" лучше заменить на "даже".