# Кому-то это(,) может(,) и нравится, но мне нет

Tags: вводные-слова

***Кому-то это(,) может(,) и нравится, но мне нет.***

Нужны тут запятые? Обе?
Мне почему-то очень режет глаз использование слова "может" в качестве вводного. Не вообще, а именно в этой короткой фразе. Его трудно изъять из текста без последствий для грамматики.

(+) ====
**UPD**
Уважаемые отвечающие. Я прошу не растекаться "мыслью по древу" и не фантазировать на тему изъятия вводного.
**Возможность изъятия из текста вводного слова или сочетания без нарушения грамматики является основополагающим свойством вводного слова, диктуемого самим его определением.**
Никаких исключений и оговорок тут быть не может в принципе. По крайней мере пока вы не ввели собственного определения вводного слова, чего, понятно, никто делать не собирается. В рамках же существующей системы все разговоры по поводу исключений или каких-то особых приемов - тарабарщина (чтобы не сказать "галиматья и ахинея").

Answer (score 1):

Расширенный комментарий.

Вопрос по поводу "может и" несколько раз поднимался на нашем форуме (и на других лингвофорумах тоже). Стороны обычно спорят вокруг аргумента "можно/нельзя изъять".

Я отмечу несколько моментов со своей точки зрения. Справочник вводных слов O.A. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамполь оптимистично утверждает, что по тем определениям вводности, которые они дают, всё всегда просто и однозначно понятно. Но вот несколько цитат классиков из этого справочника (выделение моё):

> А, впрочем вы, как сердцевед и циник, **может и** предчувствуете, что
> это несомненно так будет (Ф. Достоевский);
> К тому же, кто знает,
> может, ты и прав, **может, и** вправду нам все  это просто показывают
> (М. Булгаков);
> Она, **может, и** теплая, но она видите ли, не работает
> (М.Булгаков).

К сожалению, в пределах справочника я не нашёл объяснений, чем отличается первая цитата от остальных. Не исключаю, что в первом предложении тоже нужна запятая (и, кстати, ровно в половине изданий, до которых я дотянулся, она стоит). В любом случае понятно, что вопрос не очевидный.

Я считаю, что вполне можно переставить *может* в начало обсуждаемого предложения без критических последствий для грамматики:

**Может, кому-то это и нравится, но мне нет.**

*Может* в этом предложении имеет те же функции, что и в первоначальном, и данная перестановка не меняет существенно смысл предложения. Изъять *может* из полученного предложения ничуть не проще, чем из первоначального, но сомнений в вводности у меня остаётся намного меньше. Так что решение вопроса я предлагаю искать в специфике употребления усилительных частиц.

Comment: *несколько раз поднимался на нашем форуме* - ссылочкой не побалуете? А то я не помню такого и поиск не находит..

Comment: А вообще - спасибо. Хотя вы тоже, похоже, не с той стороны на вопрос смотрите. Для меня вопрос "можно ли изъять" не стоит ребром. Если вводное - то изъять можно. Без вариантов, по определению. Вопрос, если не ставить телегу впереди лошади, в том, вводное ли это "может". В данном конкретном случае.  Критерием (за неимением других) я полагаю наличие или отсутствие синтаксических связей. И вот-тут для меня камень преткновения.

Comment: (продолжение) И вот ваше предложение "*Решение вопроса ... искать в специфике употребления усилительных частиц*" - в корне противоречит представлению об осутствии синтаксических связей.

Comment: @behemothus [Ссылка 1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/468048/183462]), [Ссылка 2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/6127/183462]), ну и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/444440/183462) тоже сколько-то об этом. Ответа на вопрос у меня нет, это был только комментарий.

Comment: За ссылки - спасибо. Надо ж, сам отвечал 10 почти лет назад, но все забыл. Правда, там и вопрос по-другому стоял. так что нельзя даже сказать, что я мнение изменил. Напротив, я и тогда и сейчас выступаю категорически против какого-то грамматического влияния частицы на квалификацию "может" как вводного.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые нужны. Чтобы не было запятых, нужно добавить мягкий знак:
*Кому-то это может (что делать?) и нравиться, но мне нет.* || Тогда глагол, а не вводное слово.

При усилительной частице изъятие обычно не очень удачно, но вводное слово выделяется, например:
*— Тут нет того, что я ищу.

— Может, и есть.* || Вообще ерунда получается при изъятии, но запятая и в таких случаях ставится. Иначе + 2 варианта смысла:
*Он может [что-то] и есть (находится) [где-то].

Он может и есть (кушать) [что-то].*
Вот в этом примере серьёзные последствия от изъятия, а в заданном без вводного слова допустимо (звучит сносно):
*Кому-то это и нравится, но мне нет.*

Какой можно сделать вывод? Принцип изъятия не всегда работает безупречно. Частица "и" употребляется из-за вводного слова, без него необходимости в частице часто нет и она как бы лишняя. Но это не исключение (запятые ставятся).

Comment: Всё это очень, конечно, интересно, но есть вопросы. Первый. Вы действительно полагаете, что возможность изъятия вводной части не есть абсолютный признак (слово "принцип" я тут использовать категорически не хочу), а лишь некий вспомогательный инструмент, не несущий имеративной силы?

Comment: Если так, то каким определением вводного слова вы предлагаете пользоваться? Все известные мне определения так или иначе завязаны на том, что вводная часть не имеет синтаксических связей с основной, то есть вполне допускается изъятие вводной без нарушения грамматики.

Comment: Оно обычно работает, но есть исключения (почти абсолютный признак), по крайней мере одно (с другими не сталкивался). Синтаксических связей здесь нет (членов предложения, возможности поставить вопрос), но есть другое: связь, как в устойчивых сочетаниях. То есть в "может, и" есть некая устойчивость. Вот хорошее определение (оно не затрагивает синтаксис): Слово внутри другого предложения, выражающее отношение говорящего к тому, о чём он говорит.

Comment: Вы запутались окончательно. Признак быват абсолютным (он же - характеристический) тогда и только тогда, когда он (или его синоним) положен в основу определения понятия. Обойти его его таким образом невозможно. Никаких "почти" в этом случае не бывает. Это первое.

Comment: Но это ваше слово (решил перейти на него, чтоб вас не злить), мне нравится "принцип" (то, как мы действуем), а лучше — "способ [проверки]".

Comment: Второе. То, что "нет синтаксических связей",  как раз и означает возможность изъятия вводной части - без каких либо оговорок. Иначе всё это просто трудно понять. Таким образом, ваша система представлений - противоречива.  Иногда на такое идут (вне точных наук), но это от безвыходности, при определении фундаментальных понятий, но здесь я не вижк причин для введения такой странной систематики.

Comment: *Но это ваше слово* - "слово" я бы еще стерпел. Но вы запутались в собственных рассуждениях.

Comment: Есть же поговорка "везде есть исключения". После вводного слова "может" часто ставят частицу И, а без него она не кстати, а порой и неуместна. Вот такая история. Как называется такая связь с точки зрения классификации — думаю, вам лучше известно (классификациями не увлекаюсь). Не занимаюсь оценкой корректности определений терминов. Лингвисты могли и не знать (не сталкиваться ранее), что есть такое исключение, когда давали определение, которое широко распространилось. Либо это не синтаксическая связь, а какая-то другая.

Comment: Есть же куча вводных слов, зависящих от места в предложении. Например, союз-вводное слово "однако". Если вначале предложения, то союз, если в середине, то вводное слово. Или вводное слово "Первое". По основному вопросу, согласен с begemothus, что есть некая зависимость от порядка слов. И с oleedd, что слово вводное и запятые требуются. Другая ситуация будет, если заменить частицу "и" на частицу "ведь". Тогда частица будет относиться к вводному слову.

Comment: @user190920 Что-то не уловил, где говорилось о порядке слов.

Comment: Ну так возможность произвольного изменения порядка равносильна возможности изъятия без потери смысла. Например "Кому-то это и нравится, возможно" -- это предложение имеет ровно те же проблемы, что и "Кому-то это и нравится"

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим такое предложение

```
Может быть, что и есть.
```

Каково здесь придаточное предложение? "и есть"? Простите, но это же не предложение. Я бы сказал, что **что и** составной союз, а придаточное просто **есть**.

Если теперь мы опускаем союз **что**, то предложение превращается в

```
Может, и есть.
```

Поскольку нарушилась грамматика, мы вынуждены объявить всю главную часть (может быть) вводной конструкцией. Куда же отнести обломок союза - "что и"? Явно не в основное предложение. Тогда может к вводной конструкции? Ну да, только надо иметь в виду, что запятая там ставится вместо союза **что** (перед ним), после же частицы-союза **и** запятая не ставится, так как в исходном предложении её там нет.

Итак, конструкцию **Может, и** мы называем вводной, целостной конструкцией, на основании пропуска **что**. Но запятую после **и** не ставим на основании её отсутствия при восстановлении **что**.

Аналогично в примере

```
Кому-то это, (может, и) нравится, но мне нет.
```

Таким образом, проверка на вводность этого слова путем изъятия, должна осуществляться только вместе с изъятием частицы-союза **и**. Тогда все работает, тесты проходятся.

Что касается ограниченной свободы позиционирования этой вводной конструкции внутри предложения, то это вещь не новая. Есть множество вводных конструкций с ограниченным позиционированием. Например, союз-перевертыш **однако** или порядковое вводное слово **Первое**.

Comment: Составные союзы есть в списках составных союзов, а "что и" — союз + усилительная частица. *Если теперь мы опускаем союз что, то предложение превращается в Может, и есть* — нет, в "Может быть, и есть".

Comment: *Кому-то это, (может, и)* — здесь надо первую запятую за скобку.

Comment: Ну классификации составных союзов условны, я обосновал почему необходимо выделить именно такой союз - тупо потому, что иначе придаточное предложение некорректно.

Comment: Про целостность согласен, про неё говорю в ответе и комментариях. Но вот И в союз не входит, доказательство такое: *Может быть, что так оно и есть.* Союзы так не разделяются.

Comment: Это ничему не противоречит. В вашем предложении и- частица, в моем- составной союз.

Comment: В составные союзы нельзя ничего вставить, а у вас можно.

Comment: В составные союзы можно многое вставить: чем больше, тем тяжелее. Но я у себя ничего не вставляю!

Comment: Это уже двойной союз.

Comment: Двойные союзы относятся к составным. Но еще раз - я ничего не вставляю.

Comment: Между частями двойного союза обязательно ставится запятая.

Comment: У меня не двойной.

Comment: Тогда слова не должны вставляться.

Comment: У меня и не вставляются. Когда вы вставляете слова в мое предложение, то мой частица-союз переходит в чистую частицу.

Comment: Тогда это не союз, а симулянт) Нельзя считать союзом только исходя из того, что оно стоит в начале. Оно должно быть неделимым.

Comment: Союзом можно считать все, что выделяет целостное предложение. Что И - выделяет, Что - нет.

Comment: Протестую, но насчёт классификаций спорить не хочу, оно того не стоит. Главное — результат на практике.

Comment: user190920, *Каково здесь придаточное предложение?*  - простите, но речь не о придаточном а о вводном слове. Пока вы путаетесь в этих вещах, то информации в вашем ответе - чуть меньше, чем никакой.

Comment: *Таким образом, проверка на вводность этого слова путем изъятия, должна осуществляться только вместе с изъятием частицы-союза и.* - простите, это можно как-то обосновать в рамках существующих моделей грамматики? По сути вы делаете ту же ошибку, что и ваш собеседник. Пытаетесь обосновать какие-то приемы, нарушающие системность понятия, оставая при этом в рамках той системы, которую по сути отвергаете.